# Meteor Google user picture not found using Iron-Router (without page refresh)

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, meteor-accounts

Within a Meteor app, I have a publication that returns the following:

```
Meteor.users.find({_id:userId},{fields:{
"profile.name":1,
"services.facebook.email":1,
"services.google.email":1,
"profile.picture":1,
"services.google.picture":1}})
```

I am employing the accounts-google and accounts-facebook packages.

Using iron-router, my route has a waitOn function that subscribes to this publication. **When I access the page through an internal link, the Google picture image doesn't display (and cannot be seen in a console find), but when I refresh the page, it does appear.**

I'm getting the `services.google.email` field, but not the `services.google.picture`. These are both being returned from a template helper function. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Are you loading the services.google.picture value in your template through a reactive variable like helper, which is querying directly the minimongoDB? If that the case, put a debugger in that helper and check the returned value for services.google.picture.

Comment: Please, also do in your browser: "view source code" the first time the page is loaded.   Check on it if the image path is ok.  I suppose not, but let's check.

Comment: @Ruben I _am_ loading the picture url from a helper. Now that I see it, I'm pulling up `undefined` within that helper. Oddly, enough, viewing the source code does show the correct image path, but inspecting the element shows a blank img src.